# Add tag to a custom post type doesn't change the total of custom post type in backend

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I add a tag to a custom post type nammed "session" programmatically like this :

```
 wp_add_post_tags( $session->ID, "annule");
```

I tried this as well

```
 wp_set_post_tags( $session->ID, "annule", false);
```

Both case, my tag is added to my session.

But if i go in the backend and check Session > Tags

URL : /wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag&post_type=session

The total on the column is at 0.

If i click on 0 and go to see the list

URL : /wp-admin/edit.php?tag=annule&post_type=session

I can see my session that i just added before

How this is possible ?
What can i do to make the total correct ?

Note : If i add my tag manualy through the backend, the total works directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are tags counted? Can it be trigered manually?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11146/when-are-tags-counted-can-it-be-trigered-manually)

Comment: @kero, thanks reply a part. But it doesn't works. I suppose i do something wrong

$update_taxonomy = 'post_tag';
                $get_terms_args = array(
                        'taxonomy' => $update_taxonomy,
                        'hide_empty' => false,
                        );                      
                $update_terms = get_terms($get_terms_args);
                wp_update_term_count_now($update_terms,  $update_taxonomy);